# Run URL to download a file with python

Tags: python

I'm working on a program that downloads data from a series of `URLs`, like this:

`https://server/api/getsensordetails.xmlid=sesnsorID&username=user&password=password`

the program goes through a list with IDs (about 2500) and running the `URL`, try to do it using the following code

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open(url)
```

but this code implies to open the `URL` in the browser and confirm if I want to download, I need him to simply download the files without opening a browser and much less without having to confirm

thanks for everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Requests` library.

```
import requests

print('Beginning file download with requests')

url = 'http://PathToFile.jpg'  
r = requests.get(url)

with open('pathOfFileToReceiveDownload.jpg', 'wb') as f:  
    f.write(r.content)
```

Comment: thats give me a certificate error, [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:600)'),)) Is there a way to skip certificate verification?

Comment: it works, but it's very slow and I need to make 2,500 downloads of that type(file weight it's 2kb, its a xml)